# set SelectedItem in a Combobox filled with Objects - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

How can I set the selectedItem of a combobox?

The combobox is filled with EF entities same as the value that I try to set

I try different ways with no results:

```
set { cboRubroPadre.SelectedItem = value; }

set { cboRubroPadre.SelectedItem = cboRubroPadre.FindString(value.Nombre); }

set { cboRubroPadre.SelectedItem = cboRubroPadre.FindStringExact(value.Nombre); }
```

this is the combo code's:

```
cboRubroPadre.DataSource = _context.Rubros.ToList();
cboRubroPadre.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
cboRubroPadre.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the combo is filled from a different contexts and the compare is made by reference.

You need to implement == on Rubro entity or something like this:

```
foreach (var item in cboRubroPadre.Items)
    if (((Rubro)item).Nombre == value.Nombre)
    {
        cboRubroPadre.SelectedItem = item;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I already rewite the code to use a single context, I figured it might be a problem when comparing objects